# solving a trigonometric differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

could anybody please show me how to solve

$$y''+ 2y'+2y = 10 \cos(t)\ ?$$

I found the $Y_c$ , but I have problems figuring out the particular solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If this question is related to the Mathematica software, I suggest posting the related code you've come up to. If it doesn't, please delete this question and post it elsewhere.

Comment: This is covered in standard textbooks on differential equations.  Perhaps it's in yours?

Answer (score 2):

Hint, use Undetermined Coefficients by choosing:

$$y_p = a \cos t + b \sin t$$

Sub back into ODE and solve for constants and you will find:

$$a = 2, b = 4$$

For the complimentary solution, you should have:

$$y_c = e^{-t}~(c_1  \cos t + c_2 \sin t)$$